# Good edit has been rejected by community

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I edited the question because it has unnecessary words like `hello all`, and I am clear that those words isn't necessary. Am I correct?

[image]

Comment: Well, I think you are correct that these words should be removed. But you missed other things to be corrected in this post, for example formatting of code.

Comment: The reviewer chose *reject and edit*, rather than *improve* because they felt that only removing *Hello all.* was not enough.

Answer (score 29):

The reviewer chose *reject and edit*, rather than *improve* because they felt that only removing *Hello all.* was not enough. You could have removed the extra indentation and fixed `its` to `it's`, at the very least. The reviewer went on to make a [better improvement to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3876172/revisions) when they rejected the edit.

You appear to be searching for posts with greetings in them, and removing just those parts. Please **stop** doing that. Try to improve the whole post, not just focus on one little aspect.

I've rejected [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9276716) as an extreme example of you missing an opportunity to actually improve a post. Why did you leave the vast majority of the text as a code block? The whole post needs editing there, removing just the *thanks* line is far from sufficient.

Other edits are marginally better, but if you don't improve your editing skills you will end up being banned from making edit suggestions.